# Why does my chatgpt implementation not work and gives a JSON error

Tags: python, terminal, command-line-interface, openai-api

I'm working on a terminal version of ChatGPT and I found this implementation without using an API Key.

Link: https://github.com/PawanOsman/ChatGPT

Here is my code

```
def chatGPT():
    global chatgptLogo
    chatgptLogo = '''
               ((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((                  
          (((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((         
       (((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((      
    ((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((,   
   ((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((#@@@(((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((  
  (((((((((((((((((((((((((((@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((( 
 (((((((((((((((((((((((((@@@@@@((((((((((@@@@@@@@@@@@@(((((((((((((((((((((((((
 (((((((((((((((((((((((@@@@@((((((((((((((@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@(((((((((((((((((((
(((((((((((((((((((((((@@@@(((((((((((@@@@@@@@(((((((((((@@@@@@(((((((((((((((((
((((((((((((((((((@@@@@@@@((((((((@@@@@@@@((((((((((((((((((@@@@@(((((((((((((((
(((((((((((((((@@@@@@(@@@@(((((@@@@@@@((((((((((@@@(((((((((((@@@@((((((((((((((
(((((((((((((@@@@@((((@@@@(((((@@@&((((((((%@@@@@@@@@@@@(((((((@@@@(((((((((((((
((((((((((((@@@@((((((@@@@(((((@@@&((((@@@@@@@((((((@@@@@@@@(((@@@@(((((((((((((
(((((((((((@@@@(((((((@@@@(((((@@@&@@@@@@@@@@@((((((((((@@@@@@@@@@@(((((((((((((
(((((((((((@@@@(((((((@@@@(((((@@@@@@(((((((@@@@@@(((((((((((@@@@@@(((((((((((((
(((((((((((@@@@(((((((@@@@(((((@@@&(((((((((((@@@@@@@@@(((((((((@@@@((((((((((((
(((((((((((%@@@@((((((@@@@@@@((@@@&(((((((((((@@@@((@@@@@@@((((((@@@@(((((((((((
(((((((((((((@@@@(((((((((@@@@@@@@&(((((((((((@@@@(((((@@@@(((((((@@@@((((((((((
((((((((((((((@@@@@@(((((((((((@@@@@@((((((&@@@@@@(((((@@@@(((((((@@@@((((((((((
((((((((((((((@@@@@@@@@@@((((((((((@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@(((((@@@@(((((((@@@@((((((((((
((((((((((((((@@@@(((@@@@@@@@((((((@@@@@@@((((@@@@(((((@@@@((((((@@@@(((((((((((
((((((((((((((@@@@(((((((@@@@@@@@@@@@(((((((((@@@@(((((@@@@((((@@@@@((((((((((((
(((((((((((((((@@@@(((((((((((@@@((((((((((@@@@@@@(((((@@@@@@@@@@@((((((((((((((
((((((((((((((((@@@@@((((((((((((((((((@@@@@@@@((((((((@@@@@@@@(((((((((((((((((
((((((((((((((((((@@@@@@((((((((((%@@@@@@@#(((((((((((@@@@((((((((((((((((((((((
 (((((((((((((((((((@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@((((((((((((((@@@@@((((((((((((((((((((((
 (((((((((((((((((((((((((@@@@@@@@@@@@@(((((((((&@@@@@@((((((((((((((((((((((((
  (((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@((((((((((((((((((((((((((
   (((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((%@%((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((
    ((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((
       ((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((
          ((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((
             (((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((    

         _____ _           _    _____ _____ _______    _____ _      _____ 
        / ____| |         | |  / ____|  __ \__   __|  / ____| |    |_   _|
       | |    | |__   __ _| |_| |  __| |__) | | |    | |    | |      | |  
       | |    | '_ \ / _` | __| | |_ |  ___/  | |    | |    | |      | |  
       | |____| | | | (_| | |_| |__| | |      | |    | |____| |____ _| |_ 
        \_____|_| |_|\__,_|\__|\_____|_|      |_|     \_____|______|_____|
                                                                                                                           
    '''

    print(term.lemonchiffon4(chatgptLogo))
    def get_response(text, lang):
        params = {'text': text, 'lang': lang}
        response = requests.get('https://api.pawan.krd/chat/gpt', params=params)
        return response.json()
    #import urllib.request
    #contents = urllib.request.urlopen("https://api.pawan.krd/chat/gpt").read()
    print("Yes, the REAL ChatGPT in PyPrompt!")
    print("This is a special API which uses ChatGPT but without an OpenAI key!")
    print(" ")
    print("DISCLAIMER: Please do NOT use this for cheating purposes at school or college.")
    print(" ")
    chat = input("Say something to ChatGPT: ")
    response = get_response(chat, 'en')
    print(response)
```

This is what I got, can someone help me

Traceback (most recent call last):
File "C:\Users\s40114337\AppData\Local\Packages\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.10_qbz5n2kfra8p0\LocalCache\local-packages\Python310\site-packages\requests\models.py", line 971, in json
return complexjson.loads(self.text, **kwargs)
File "C:\Program Files\WindowsApps\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.10_3.10.2800.0_x64__qbz5n2kfra8p0\lib\json_*init*_.py", line 346, in loads
return _default_decoder.decode(s)
File "C:\Program Files\WindowsApps\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.10_3.10.2800.0_x64__qbz5n2kfra8p0\lib\json\decoder.py", line 337, in decode
obj, end = self.raw_decode(s, idx=_w(s, 0).end())
File "C:\Program Files\WindowsApps\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.10_3.10.2800.0_x64__qbz5n2kfra8p0\lib\json\decoder.py", line 355, in raw_decode
raise JSONDecodeError("Expecting value", s, err.value) from None
json.decoder.JSONDecodeError: Expecting value: line 1 column 1 (char 0)

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
File "c:\Users\s40114337\Downloads\PyPrompt Development\main.py", line 1177, in 
main(current_dir)
File "c:\Users\s40114337\Downloads\PyPrompt Development\main.py", line 315, in main
whatiscommand(current_dir)
File "c:\Users\s40114337\Downloads\PyPrompt Development\main.py", line 300, in whatiscommand
chatGPT()
File "c:\Users\s40114337\Downloads\PyPrompt Development\main.py", line 1164, in chatGPT
response = get_response(chat, lang)
File "c:\Users\s40114337\Downloads\PyPrompt Development\main.py", line 1109, in get_response
return response.json()
File "C:\Users\s40114337\AppData\Local\Packages\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.10_qbz5n2kfra8p0\LocalCache\local-packages\Python310\site-packages\requests\models.py", line 975, in json
raise RequestsJSONDecodeError(e.msg, e.doc, e.pos)
requests.exceptions.JSONDecodeError: Expecting value: line 1 column 1 (char 0)

Comment: The website https://api.pawan.krd/chat/gpt is closed, if you print the variable `response`, you will get an error state of 502. Which means a Bad Gateway of the server.